# Clustering Markov Chains

Tags: distributions, clustering, markov-process

Assume I have a finite set of elements 
$$A={X_0,X_1,...,X_{n_1}}$$
where every element is itself a finite Markov sequence (i.e. $S_{i+1} \sim P(S_i)$)
$$X_i={S_0,S_1,...,S_{n_2}}$$

Suppose I also have a set of transition matrices 
$$P={P_0,P_1,...,P_{n_3}}$$

My problem is as follows: I know $n_1$ and $n_2$ (i.e. I have sampled a set of sequences) but I do not know $n_3$ (i.e. I do not know how many transition matrices there are and henceforth do not know how they look like). In addition I do not know which transition matrix $P_i$ was used for every Markov sequence $X_j$. Is there any way I can cluster the Markov sequences $X_j$ to belong to transition matrix $P_i$?

For example: $(X_0, X_3, X_5)$ were most likely generated using $P_0$, $(X_1, X_2, X_6)$ were most likely generated using $P_1$ etc.

I can imagine there are two problems to solve here:

1. How to determine the amount of transition matrices (i.e. the amount of clustering groups)
2. How to cluster the Markov sequences to belong to such a certain group.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated! Perhaps there is a well known method on how to accomplish this or maybe you can think of some method that might be able to achieve this?

Comment: In other words, you have observations from an unknown number of distributions and want to cluster them by distribution. This can be done by model comparison, a model being defined by a value of $n_3$.

Comment: Could you please expand on this answer @Xi'an?